# tabindex attribute for asp.net server-side panel control not being translated in client side

Tags: asp.net, tabindex

In my asp.net project I have a panel control that has the TabIndex attribute set.  Example:

```
<asp:Panel ID="myPanel" runat="server" TabIndex="0"></asp:Panel>
```

My expectation is that when the code was converted to client side that it would look like this:

```
<div id="myPanel" tabindex='0'></div>
```

But when I view the source on the client side I see no tabindex attribute at all.  It is as if ASP.Net ignored the tabindex attribute.

Why is the attribute not translated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being removed because TabIndex="0" is the default (meaning no tab order) for asp.net web controls.  Even though tabindex="0" is valid for the div that asp.net panels get converted to on the client side, TabIndex="0" will not be translated.  The TabIndex must be 1 or greater to be translated.